# Is velocity measured with respect to the coordinate time or proper time?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, velocity, observers

In General Relativity, is the velocity of a body measured with respect to coordinate time or proper time?
Also, is the method for measuring the velocity of light different from that of mass, in a curved coordinate frame?

Comment: Depends on the context. What are you measuring and how are you doing it? In general it will be a very difficult question to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both. The one measured with respect to proper time is the tangent vector to the trajectory $\gamma(s)=(x^\mu(s))$, on spacetime, the "four-velocity",

$$u(s)=u^\mu(s)\partial_\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{ds}\partial_\mu.$$

The paramenter $s$ is usually chosen so that $u$ is normalized to $1$, i.e. $g_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu=1$. The other thing is coordinate velocity, which is the ratio of spatial displacement to time displacement,

$$v^i=\frac{u^i}{u^t}=\frac{dx^i}{dx^t}=\frac{dr_i}{dt}.$$

Note that this only makes sense when you're looking at a pseudo-Riemannian manifold where $t$ has the opposite sign eigenvalue in the metric when compared to the other $i$ coordinates. In a context where all coordinates have the same sign, there's nothing special about the "first" to warrant a definition of velocity with respect to it.